# pcap.h header file problem

Tags: ubuntu-10.10

anyone know how to fix the problem regarding  header file in ubuntu 10.10.
I am executing a sniffing program which makes use of this header file. My system shows libcap package is installed. Still, on compiling the code, an error is coming which reads:

fatal error: pcap.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

Please help me out.

Thanks all:)

Answer (score 68):

The system won't let me correct Eric Fossum's comment, because I lack reputation. There is a typo ("libcap" vs. "libpcap") and his suggested command should read the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libpcap-dev
```

Comment: I tried this, still its giving me error fatal error: libpcap/pcap.h: No such file or directory. #include <libpcap/pcap.h>

Comment: I think you should include it like this: `#include <pcap.h>`

Answer (score 52):

```
sudo apt-get install libpcap0.8-dev
```

Comment: or try `sudo apt-get install libcap-dev` to better suite your OS's update system

Comment: Actually, the original answer is 'correct'. Out the box you may be wanting to install something and just get it to work. If you run `sudo apt-get install libpcap0.8-dev` then you are good to go, if you don't get the 0.8 bit in there then you'll still be hunting around for where the pcap.h file is and trying to put it into a path somehow.

Comment: @EricFossum just for the record - you probably ment `libpcap-dev`, you have a typo. So I'm leaving this comment to prevent others from dumb cccv like I did

Answer (score 4):

If you are using yum, then

```
sudo yum install install libpcap-devel
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't have the pcap.h file in your include path.  You need to add the location of pcap.h to your include path when compiling:

-I/path/to/pcap.h

Answer (score 3):

If you're using linuxbrew, you can just `brew install libpcap`. In my case I was trying to install `nethogs` and it failed with this error.

Answer (score 1):

First install libpcap:

```
sudo apt-get install libpcap0.8-dev
```

then create its **shortcut for header** file:

```
ln -s /usr/include/pcap/bpf.h /usr/include/net/bpf.h
```

Comment: Shouldn't that link have been done automatically?

Comment: as usual 'yes' but maybe the make script was not configured well then, some conflicts will be happened...