# How to solve this "pip install pypcap" error (both in Windows and Ubuntu Linux)

Tags: python, pip

I get this error:

when I try to install the pypcap library (for Python 2.7.x) on either Windows 7 or Ubuntu 12.04:

The following is the Windows version of the error, but the Linux error is similar, and can post it later:

```
$ pip install pypcap -U
Collecting pypcap
  Using cached pypcap-1.1.5.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    pcap.h not found

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\
<username>\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-qjf6rt\pypcap\
```

Thanks for any pointers or advice on this.

Answer (score 4):

You need the pcap development library.

On linux, try

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libpcap0.8-dev
```

I know nothing of Windows.

Link to [relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5779784/pcap-h-header-file-problem).

Comment: Thanks, Louis. The problem is now solved after I did a variation of what you suggested (googled some and the command you gave did not work, but this similar one did):

apt-get install libpcap0.8-dev

Comment: great! I changed my answer to reflect what worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

The c library that `pypcap` depends on is not installed on your machine.

I suggest using [Miniconda](https://conda.io/miniconda.html) to manage your entire Python environment.  You can install compiled packages for your architecture to your local conda environment, and then your `pip` command will succeed.

Comment: Thanks. Will try that. Had actually thought using Anaconda myself, since I knew it has many more packages, and guessed some of them could be compiled ones. But ran out of disk space, for some reason, though doing df first, showed plenty of space. Going to try it or Miniconda again.